# Paths and text inside them

Tags: photoshop

I need to put text inside a big "6". I have my path, and the text is fitting in it.

However the text absolutely refuses to go around the hole in the middle of the 6 even though they're part of the same path.

How do I do this?

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNpce.png)

[Text not warping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1R11.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Type 6 or any character
2. Just right click on this layer and select "Rasterize Type". Now your text layer convert from text to simple object.
3. Now paste the required image above this layer.
4. and now press Alt Key and click on this image

Simple  :)

This is called text masking in Photoshop. 
If you have any question just let me know.